# MySQL Create new table while tables locked

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-migration

Is it possible to create a new table while there is a current lock on existing tables?

I'm setting a lock on all current tables while the system migrations are processing, but for those migrations which create a new table I get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1100 Table 'xxx' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`

From what I understand, to interact with any table outside of the locked ones, you either need to include it into the lock or drop the lock all together but in this situation I can't add the table as it isn't created yet & don't want to drop the lock in the middle of the migration.

Comment: Can you create all the new tables before locking?

Comment: @Barmar I could restructure the migration files so any new tables are created before the lock, ideally would prefer not having to do that - but that could work